# Adobe Javascript Apply Password Protection

Tags: javascript, security, passwords, adobe, policy

I have a javascript that will extract pages from a pdf document, apply an existing Acrobat security policy (to password protect the document from changes) and save them. This all works well, however Adobe still keeps prompting with the Password Security - Settings dialog window for each file. Can someone recommend a way to automatically do this without the window opening, either in the Javascript or in the policy? I am using Pro XI.

Code

```
var rtn = Currpage.encryptUsingPolicy({oPolicy: oMyPolicy })
```

Where:

```
var sPolicyName = "MyCerts";
app.beginPriv();
var AllPolicies = security.getSecurityPolicies();
for(var i=0; i<AllPolicies.length; i++)
{
     if(AllPolicies[i].name == sPolicyName)
     {
          oMyPolicy = AllPolicies[i];
          break;
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Jeff